# Why won't my image center when using 'margin: 0 auto'

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a new version of the [Textastic](http://textasticapp.com/) website for fun as something to put to my portfolio. I'm having an issue with getting the image to center. On the image I have the following styles:

```
.download {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The image moves, but only a little bit to the right, and not in the center. Could someone take a look at the source and help me fix this problem and tell me why it's happening?

[Website](http://jordanbaron.me/Updated-Textastic-Site)

[Github Repo](https://github.com/jrdnbrn/Updated-Textastic-Site)

P.S This probably will be something simple so pardon my lack of experience :)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: add `clear: both` to `.download`

Comment: @Quentin My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `.author` element has `float: right;` which conflicts with your image. 
You can for example add a div before your image with a `clear: both;` it will stop `.author` from conflicting.

BTW, no need to set `width: 100%;` on block elements like `div` since this is their default behavior.

Floats can sometime be pains in the a**. An easier and more logical way to align your text to the right would be to set `text-align: right;` to `.author` and make them `p` or `div`.

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much!